# Using GA4 Pages and Screens from .Net MAUI

Tags: google-analytics, maui, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

I have a .Net MAUI app. I need to provide information of its usage to Google Analytics (GA4). Specifically, I want to show statistics of visiting the app's screens in the Pages and Screens section.
Currently, I can send events information using package Plugin.Firebase, but I am not sure it can handle Pages and Screens. I found the following statement about using Packages and Screens:

> When you first access the report, you’ll see your data broken down
> according to page title and screen class. This means you’re looking at
> all the pages on your site, broken down by the web page title and the
> developer-supplied screen name.

I cannot figure out how I can supply the screen name. Currently, for the screen name Pages and Screens has "Not Set", which is not useful at all.

Comment: (I've never used GA.) If no one has a better answer, then do [Manually track screens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#manually_track_screens).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you for your comment. Yes, I was able to do that in C#, and it worked! You may want to make it an answer, I will mark it.